# Jquery if Condition that will call an Alert if string not in proper format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, alert, control-flow

Basically, I am trying to craft an if condition that will alert users if the do not enter their date in the proper format, i.e. the format (2011-09-20) it will alert users to this fact. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (and then check if it can be parsed into an actual date)

```
var testValue = "2011-09-91";

if(!testValue.match(/^[0-9]{4}(\-[0-9]{2}){2}$/) || isNaN(new Date(testValue)))
{
    alert("failure");
}
```

Comment: And a bit more could be done with this if desired to filter out things like 2011-99-99 which this will accept...

Comment: Updated to deal with invalid dates conforming to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
if ('2011-09-20'.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/))
    alert('this is maybe a date in the correct format');
else
    alert('this is not the correct format');
```